# Error cannot open database requested by login

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I created a database using Window Authentication for my application. My application works fine, but when I try to deploy it using iis 6.0 it gives this error

> Cannot open database "WebGallery" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\Pool'.

What is this error and how can I solve this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a permissions issue. Ensure that the account `APPOOL\Pool` has access to the database

Comment: @DarrenDavies thanks but i told you my database funda are not good so can you tell me some link where i can get knowledge for this and can you explain how to access database

Comment: let me tell you one thing suppose i am beginner now can you guy provide me some books or links of database so that i can do it by my self

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple: 
the user IIS APPPOOL\Pool does not have rights to access the database.

You can provide this user with rights in the SQL Server Management Studio which you've probably used to create the database.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "IIS APPPOOL\Pool" account to the database logins using SQL Management Studio or edit the application pool settings using IIS Manager so that it will use your account which is authenticated to access the database.

Comment: See guys i am very bad in database and this is my first web application which i want to deploy so can you guys provide me some link where i can get detail information about database and connectivity

Comment: nope its not the same error its a database error i am not able to connect with the database

Comment: now i got this error HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Comment: error 500 is a web server error, take a look at the logs, then post the details of the error here